# remove tr when id in .map()

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<table>
<tr class="1">
<td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr class="2">
<td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr class="4">
<td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr class="5">
<td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr class="6">
<td>value</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Every `<tr>` has a checkbox, when I check 4 checkboxes in `tr.2`, `tr.4`, `tr.5`, and `tr.6` end I click a delete button, I will get checkbox:checked in `.map()` with value 2,4,5,6. Then I will delete `tr.2`, `tr.4`, `tr.5`, and `tr.6`.
When I use `.each()`, it's not working.

help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.delete-button').on('click', function(){
        $('tr checkbox').filter(':checked').parents('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: i will process it when my ajax success, `tr` is my data from database, and i will delete it use checkbox Thanks,